# New Warning on v1.1.0.RC3 - Failed to parse csv

Tags: csv, parsing, karate

On the latest Karate version v1.1.0.RC3, I am receiving new warning messages I did not receive before and I'm struggling to determine why and if it's having any impact. Any help would be appreciated.

[pool-2-thread-1] WARN com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils - failed to parse csv: 18

**My Observations:**

- If I turn off multi threading, this warning does not occur
- It always occurs right at the start when executing features
- It did not occur on version 0.9.6
- Enabling debug did not provide any additional info
- I'm having difficulty nailing down which .csv is causing the issue. If I execute the feature that was running when this warning appears in isolation, the warning doesn't occur (IE: when running the suspected feature in isolation, no warning, but when the feature is picked up as part of multiple features, the warning does happen). I've also looked at my csvs and don't see any concerns

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: CSV Test

  Background:
    * def isGroup = function(group) { return function(list) { return group.toUpperCase() == list.group.toUpperCase(); } }

  Scenario Outline: <zephyr_id>: <zephyr_desc> - <state>
    * print test

    Examples:
      | karate.filter(read('../data/' + env + '/requests/test.csv'), isGroup('PRE')) |
```

Sample CSV:

> group,zephyr_id,zephyr_desc,expected_report_code,expected_transactions,option,account,state,option,option,option,option,century_indicator,search_period,option,option,option,quoteback,extended_qb,dln,last_name,first_name,middle_name,suffix,dob,gender,ssn
> PRE,XXX-11794,"PRE - TEST ",0000,2,,000000,TN,8,,0,0,0,B,0,Y,0,ERC
> 0000,,000000000,LASTK,FIRS,,,031185,M,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite important that you give us a way to replicate, as we are trying to resolve a certain related multi-threaded issue. Please spend some time and do this, it just means taking your test, putting it in a clean project, and swapping any sensitive data values in your CSV etc.

Here are the instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

So if you can do that - we will definitely look into it and advise.

EDIT - can you please read this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1558#issuecomment-864360775

It would be great if you can follow the [developer guide](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide) and confirm the fix works fine for you.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I retested on RC4 and I still see the warning, but it does not appear to have any negative impact. The system is reading the csv fine and my total orders created from the csv is matching what I expect. 

I tried replicating the issue by following the new project process, but didn't have any luck. Will continue to investigate

Comment: Upon more investigating, the issue appeared to be with one of our csv files itself. We have a lot of csvs, and it wasn't the csv we expected based on where the error appeared though, hence the confusion and difficulty in locating it. Thank you Peter.

Comment: @DavidA no problem. in case this is relevant - a problem was discovered recently when CSV files have unusual encoding: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1757